# Jenkins pipeline dependency between developer and qa job

Tags: selenium, jenkins-pipeline

Our developers use Bitbucket as the code repository. 
Dev Repository is: AbcdProject

We, from QA team, write selenium automation scripts. What is the right approach -

Should the automated scripts go under tests folder under the same repo as the Dev. Like:

AbcdProject/
-src
-tests
--unit
--functional
---AbcdAutomationScripts
----src
----pom.xml
----testng.xml

or we should have our own repo and our scripts should go under that repo? Like:

Dev Repo:
AbcdProject/
-src
-tests
--unit

QA Repo: 
AbcdAutomationScripts/
-src
--pom.xml
---testng.xml

I would prefer having a separate repo for QA but I would like to know the industry standard/best practice.

Considering, we go with a separate repo for QA: 
 
Right now, when the developer pushes the code in bitbucket, his jenkinsfile triggers the build and deploys the code in dev-server. But the question is how do I set the dependency in Jenkins Pipeline such that when developer's trigger of the build has completed and the code is deployed in dev-server, my selenium scripts in another repo should get executed.

Answer (score 0):

Standard is to have the tests in the same project. Consequences:

- Developers see the expectations of QA. They know what's in focus and what isn't.

  - They see if stuff is in focus that should't be, or vice versa, so this can help improve the test suite quality.
  - The downside is that devs get the option to specifically program for passing the tests instead of for improving quality. However, if this is a thing, developers aiming for the wrong goals is a symptom of deeper problems, such as developers generally being incentivized towards the wrong goals.
- Developers see what DOM access paths are being used in QA. This helps them understand what paths are expected to be stable. You get a chance to fix any miscommunications about access path stability before you run into a nightmare of "every small dev change requires adapting all Selenium scripts".
- Liability: Dev and QA need to coordinate their directory structure. Usually not a big issue and if you have a useful SCM (such as git, even svn should work) this isn't really a big problem, but the conventions need to be in place and understood by everybody.
- QA will notice if dev starts a new development branch.

Answer (score 0):

Currently i have merged automation testing code base with development code base and merged both the pom's and able to run my automation cases effectively on CI/CD pipeline y adding the stage for run tests in jenkinsfile and do mvn clean install.

Having said that, i am still looking for some better solution where i don't need to merge both pom's and handle both dev and testing code loosely coupled.